# Hover background colour not changing for last 2 elements

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the background colour of an anchor element when it's in a hover state, the problem is I am not able to achieve this with style I have below.

**jsfiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/fwP6g/

**css**

```
    .dropdown ul{
        margin:0; padding:0; float:left; width:100%; 
    }

    .dropdown ul li{
        list-style:none; float:left; width:100%;
    }

    .dropdown ul li a{
        float:left; width: 265px;  height:20px; padding:5px; 
        padding-top:10px; color:#000;  font-size:12px;  
        border-bottom:1px dotted #666;  background-color:#FFF;
    }

    .dropdown ul li a:hover{
        background-color:#F80101;  !important
    }

    .dropdown ul li:last-child a{
        border-bottom:none;
    }

    .dropdown ul li a#pink{
        background-color:#FFE8E8;
    }
```

**html**

```
<div class="dropdown"> 
     <ul>
            <li><a href="/orders">Orders</a></li>
            <li><a href="/favourites">Favourites</a></li>
            <li><a href="/account" style="background-color:#FFE8E8;">Account</a></li>
            <li><a href="/settings" style="background-color:#FFE8E8;">Settings</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

I'm confused, I don't why this is not working, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you are using the same id `pink` for both elements.

Comment: Sorry the original was different

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `!important` needs to go before the closing `;`.

```
.dropdown ul li a:hover {
    background-color:#F80101 !important; 
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fwP6g/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

It's not semantically correct to have two elements with the same id. Also, using ids for your selector gives the rule a very high precedence, which is why you need to use `!important`.

I would suggest giving the last 2 list item links a **class** of pink instead of an id.

Then you would just need to declare the `.pink` rule before the `:hover` rule. Since both rules have the same precedence, and the `:hover` rule comes after, it will override the `.pink` rule.

http://jsfiddle.net/fwP6g/2/

#### HTML

```
...
<li><a href="/account" class='pink'>Account</a></li>
<li><a href="/settings" class="pink">Settings</a></li>
...
```

#### CSS

```
.dropdown ul li a.pink{
    background-color:#FFE8E8;
}
.dropdown ul li a:hover{
    background-color:#F80101;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your id="pink" to class="pink", than in your css add this to your hover .dropdown ul li a.pink:hover

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

false:

```
.dropdown ul li a:hover{
        background-color:#F80101;  !important
    }
```

true:

```
.dropdown ul li a:hover{
        background-color:#F80101 !important;  
    }
```